# Photo Album Display : having effects like themes, templates

Tags: jquery, image, gallery, slideshow, photos

I am making a website, that allows users to upload photos in an album.
I want the album to be displayed to user having some effects like
themes, templates, showing text on images etc.

I am looking for something like [this](http://www.picaboo.com/photobooks/)
but this has too much options, I need a only a few.

Comment: “Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.” [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

Pick a Server side language

Pick Javascript and a library (jquery is great)

Start programming it, you can do it with anything you want.